# comandbutton is not work in included pages in primefaces project

Tags: ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, ejb

i dynamic include a xhtml page of primefaces project style in my page.
at first request i can found facesmessgae on the include page.
then the input ajax validate is not work,nothing validate,not work.
the  commandButton is not work.

**the include page**

.ui-slidemenu-content{height: 300px; }
                
                
                    $(function() {
                        $("#addfoodtogg").toggle();
                    });

```
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <ui:include src="../header.xhtml"/>
            <p:layout style="min-width:240px;min-height:650px" id="layout">  
                <p:layoutUnit id="left" position="west" size="250"  resizable="true" closable="false" collapsible="true"  header="系统管理" minSize="250" >
                    <h:form>
                        <p:slideMenu backLabel="返回" >
                            <p:submenu label="食品管理"   icon="ui-submenu-foodmanager">  
                                <p:submenu label="食品管理" icon="ui-submenu-foodsmanager">
                                    <p:menuitem value="添加食品" actionListener="#{menuManagerController.oper('addfood')}" update=":#{p:component('centerpanel')}" icon="ui-submenu-foodsmanager-add"  />  
                                    <p:menuitem value="管理食品" actionListener="#{menuManagerController.oper('managerfood')}" update=":#{p:component('centerpanel')}" icon="ui-submenu-foodsmanager-manager" />  
                                </p:submenu>
                                <p:submenu label="食品种类管理" icon="ui-submenu-foodcatemanager">
                                    <p:menuitem value="添加种类" actionListener="#{menuManagerController.oper('addfoodcate')}" update=":#{p:component('centerpanel')}" icon="ui-submenu-foodcatemanager-add " />  
                                    <p:menuitem value="管理管理" actionListener="#{menuManagerController.oper('managerfoodcate')}" update=":#{p:component('centerpanel')}" icon="ui-submenu-foodcatemanager_manager" />  
                                </p:submenu>
                            </p:submenu>  
                            <p:submenu label="菜单管理" icon="ui-submenu-foodmenumanager">
                                <p:menuitem value="添加菜单" actionListener="#{menuManagerController.oper('addfoodmenu')}" update=":#{p:component('centerpanel')}" icon="ui-submenu-foodmenumanager-add" /> 
                                <p:menuitem value="管理菜单" actionListener="#{menuManagerController.oper('managerfoodmenu')}" update=":#{p:component('centerpanel')}" icon="ui-submenu-foodmenumanager-manager" /> 
                            </p:submenu>
                            <p:submenu label="用户管理" icon="ui-submenu-usermanager">  
                                <p:menuitem value="添加用户" actionListener="#{menuManagerController.oper('adduser')}" update=":#{p:component('centerpanel')}" icon="ui-submenu-usermanager-add" />  
                                <p:menuitem value="用户管理" actionListener="#{menuManagerController.oper('manageruser')}" update=":#{p:component('centerpanel')}" icon="ui-submenu-usermanager-manager" />  
                                <p:menuitem value="权限设置" actionListener="#{menuManagerController.oper('xx')}" update=":#{p:component('centerpanel')}" icon="ui-submenu-usermanager-poweredit" />  
                            </p:submenu>  
                            <p:submenu label="系统配置" icon="ui-submenu-sysmanager">  
                                <p:menuitem value="基础配置" actionListener="#{menuManagerController.oper('xx')}" update=":#{p:component('centerpanel')}" icon="ui-submenu-sysmanager-basic" />  
                            </p:submenu>  
                        </p:slideMenu>
                    </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit position="center"> 
                    <p:panel  id="centerpanel" >
                        <ui:decorate template="#{menuManagerController.panelurl}"></ui:decorate>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:layoutUnit>  
                <p:layoutUnit position="south" ></p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>
            <ui:include src="../tail.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </h:body>
    </html>
```

**and it s included page**

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <h:head>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <p:panel>
                <h:form>
                    <p:growl id="addfoodymsg" showDetail="true"   life="3000" autoUpdate="true"/> 
                    <p:panelGrid columns="4">
                        <p:outputLabel for="foodname" value="食品名称" >
                        </p:outputLabel>
                        <p:inputText id="foodname"    value="#{foodManagerController.foodName}" >
                            <f:validateRequired/>
                            <f:validator validatorId="foodIsExistValidator"/>
                            <p:ajax update="addfoodymsg" event="keyup"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:outputLabel for="fooddesc" value="食品描述" >
                        </p:outputLabel>
                        <p:inputText id="fooddesc"    value="#{foodManagerController.foodDesc}" >
                            <f:validateRequired/>
                            <p:ajax update="addfoodymsg" event="keyup"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:outputLabel for="foodprice" value="食品价格(元)" >
                        </p:outputLabel>
                        <p:inputText id="foodprice"    value="#{foodManagerController.price}" >
                            <f:validateRequired/>
                            <f:validateDoubleRange/>
                            <p:ajax update="addfoodymsg" event="keyup"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:outputLabel for="foodUnitinput" value="计量单位">
                        </p:outputLabel>
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{foodManagerController.foodUnit}"  
                                         id="foodUnitinput" panelStyle="width:150px" effect="explode" style="width:160px" 
                                         immediate="true"
                                         >
                            <f:selectItems value="#{foodManagerController.foodUnits}" var="foodunits" 
                                           itemLabel="#{foodunits}" itemValue="#{foodunits}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:outputLabel for="favfoodprice" value="优惠价格" >
                        </p:outputLabel>
                        <p:inputText id="favfoodprice"    value="#{foodManagerController.favourablePrice}" >
                            <f:validateRequired/>
                            <f:validateDoubleRange/>
                            <p:ajax update="addfoodymsg" event="keyup"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:outputLabel for="foodcatselect" value="食品种类">
                        </p:outputLabel>
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{foodManagerController.foodCategory}"  
                                         id="foodcatselect" panelStyle="width:150px" effect="explode" style="width:160px" 
                                         converter="categoryconvertor"  immediate="true"
                                         >
                            <f:selectItems value="#{foodCateManagerController.foodCategories}" var="foodcat" 
                                           itemLabel="#{foodcat.typeName}" itemValue="#{foodcat}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:outputLabel for="foodstate" value="食品状态">
                        </p:outputLabel>
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{foodManagerController.bustate}"  
                                         id="foodstate" panelStyle="width:150px" effect="explode" style="width:160px" 
                                         immediate="true"
                                         >
                            <f:selectItems value="#{foodManagerController.foodBustate}" var="foodstate" 
                                           itemLabel="#{foodstate}" itemValue="#{foodstate}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:commandButton id="addacate"   value="添加"  actionListener="#{foodManagerController.addFood()}"  ajax="true"/>  
                </h:form>
            </p:panel>
        </h:body>
    </ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add process="@this" and check

```
<p:commandButton id="addacate" process="@this" value="添加"  actionListener="#foodManagerController.addFood()}"  ajax="true"/>
```

Comment: Please check and let us know soon so we can help you as soon as possible.

Comment: May be you have an validation error.Place<p:message autoUpdate="true" />.

Comment: Due to the validation error your invoke application phase is not called and hence commondButton seem's not to work

Comment: Adding immediate="true" will do your job

Comment: I guess this problem is regarding h:form tag with in h:form tag.
use prependId="false" for inner h:form tag

<h:form prependId="false"></h:form>

Comment: if possible avoid to use h:form with in h:form.

For your info please check last comment from this post http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20655